# code language not supported or defined. SOURCE: Code Runner(extension), How do I solve this error in VS code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

when I tried to execute a code in VS code related to HTML I got "code language not supported or defined" error. My language mode is in HTML, Code Runner is installed, but can't find a way. What should I do?

I tried changing code. I rechecked language mode, tried several times. none was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One does not really "run HTML". One can run a server that serves the HTML page, or open the HTML in a browser via the `file://` protocol. I suppose you could look for a command for your specific browser to launch an instance of it with a new tab at a specific `file://` URL. See also [the `code-runner.executorMap` setting](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner).

But really I'd suggest that you take a look at [the "Live Server" extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) if you want to locally test some local HTML <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>.